# Why can't 'tm' be registered as a variable out side the if statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
run = 1
list1 = [] 
for i in range(2):
     while run > 0 :
          print("-------------------------------------------------------")
          run = 1
          reg_num = input("Registration Number in caps: ")
          tsh = int(input("Hour Entered : "))
          tsm = int(input("Minute Entered : "))
          tss = int(input("Second Entered : "))
          print("")
          teh = int(input("Hour Exited : "))
          tem = int(input("Minute Exited : "))
          tes = int(input("Second Exited : "))
          print("Time Entered (camera1)", tsh, ":", tsm, ":", tss, "and Time Exited (camera2)", teh, ":", tem, ":", tes)
          if tsh < teh:
               tm = (((teh - tsh)*60) + (tem - tsm) +((tes - tss)/60))/60
          elif tsh > teh:
               teh = 24 + teh
               tm = (((teh - tsh)*60) + (tem - tsm) +((tes - tss)/60))/60
          speed = run/tm
          print("speed of", reg_num, "is", "{:.2f}".format(speed), "mph")
          if speed > 70:
               list1.append(reg_num)               
          break 
print("Overspeeding vehicles are: ")
for item in list1:
     print (item)
```

this is the code to calculate the speed of a vehicle that passes through a speed camera set 1 mile apart. i have to out put a list of vehicles that are exceeding the speed limit. the problem is when the code calculates the speed (speed = run/time) the error massage states that "tm"(totalminutes) is not defined. can you make some corrections and tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Care to explain what you are trying to do and what exactly is not working?

Comment: What's happening with this code? You mention one line of calculation, but why? Are you getting some kind of exception? If so, include the full traceback.

Comment: Your `if` and `elif` conditions are the same.

Comment: And because your `if/elif` statements are the same tm is never defined. if `tsh >= teh`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is none of your conditions in the 'if' statement are met.

```
if tsh = teh:
    tm = bla
elif tsh < teh:
    tm = bla * 2
else:
    tm = bla / 2 # Add the 'else' part to do something when all else fails.
```